# Some problems with parsing html pages

Tags: python, parsing, unicode, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to build program to parse html page. And in this case I cannot get url directly, so I ask users to download a html page and work with it.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from re import findall
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# INPUT
def inside(html_path, errors='ignore'):
    with open(html_path, errors=errors) as fp:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, features='lxml')
    return soup


def pairing(html_path, errors='ignore') -> dict:
    use_dict = {}

    soup = inside(html_path=html_path, errors=errors)

    for pair in zip(
            soup.find_all('div', {"class": "audio_row__performers"}),
            soup.find_all('span', {"class": "audio_row__title_inner _audio_row__title_inner"}),
            soup.find_all('span', {"class": "audio_row__title_inner_subtitle _audio_row__title_inner_subtitle"})
    ):
        """
        pair[0] - musician(-s), 
        pair[1] - track_name, 
        pair[2] - subtitle for track(if any)
        """

        track_author = pair[0].find('a').text

        pair_2_str = str(pair[2])

        regex = "(?<=>).*?(?=<)"
        add_meta = findall(regex, pair_2_str)[0]

        track_name = pair[1].text + f" {add_meta}"

        use_dict.update({track_author: track_name})
    return use_dict
```

And after execution with `errors='replace'` I get something like this:

```
('The Offspring', 'Dividing By Zero ')
('ACDC', 'Hightway to Hell ')
('����(�.�. ���)', '������ ����� �� ������ ')
('Haddaway', "What is love, baby don't hurt me. ")
("Guns N' Roses", 'Catcher in the rye ')
('Queen', 'Dont stop me now (�������� � ������)  ')
('The Subways', 'Rock & Roll Queen ')
('Fetty Wap', 'Trap Queen ')
```

I thought that I have got the wrong page, so I took a look at metadata, and,unfortunately,found this:

```
      <div class="audio_row__performer_title">
        <div onmouseover="setTitle(this)" class="audio_row__performers"><a href="https://vk.com/audio?performer=1&amp;q=%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%28%D0%92.%D0%A0.%20%D0%A6%D0%BE%D0%B9%29">Кино(В.Р. Цой)</a></div>
        <div class="audio_row__title _audio_row__title" onmouseover="setTitle(this)">
          <span class="audio_row__title_inner _audio_row__title_inner">Группа крови на рукаве</span>
          <span class="audio_row__title_inner_subtitle _audio_row__title_inner_subtitle"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="audio_row__info _audio_row__info"><div class="audio_row__duration audio_row__duration-s _audio_row__duration">3:59</div></div>
    </div>
```

It means that I've got the correct page, but decode func inside bs4 cannot detect these symbols (I got this message when have executed it with `errors='strict'`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roman/VKMusic/ParserEXE.py", line 5, in <module>
    use_dict = pairing(html_path=html_path,errors='strict')
  File "/home/roman/VKMusic/Main1.py", line 17, in pairing
    soup = inside(html_path=html_path, errors=errors)
  File "/home/roman/VKMusic/Main1.py", line 10, in inside
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, features='lxml')
  File "/home/roman/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 306, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
  File "/home/roman/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 457: invalid continuation byte
```

HTML page in this case was downloaded with Google Chrome (on Linux(Ubuntu) by myself and on Windows 7 by my friend. Both have the same result), but I also tried with Firefox and ran into this error aswell.
I need my code parsing entire html, including cyrillic symbols.

Link to example of html page: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FKhTlVErjAKI9L2iedJtmHaXpoyCBMdl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It _looks_ as if the original html is encoded as utf-8, but is being saved as another encoding, perhaps one of the windows cp125* encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function 'inside' replace
`with open(html_path, errors=errors) as fp:`

to

`with open(html_path, errors=errors, encoding='cp1251') as fp:`

Output:

...

'Чёрные Озёра': 'За 6 дней ',
'Чёрные Озёра и Мария Немцева': 'Отпусти ',
'Шарль Гуно ': 'Опера "Фауст", Вальпургиева ночь - Античный танец ["Маски в '
'Опере - 2"] ',
'Шопен': 'Этюд «Революционый» №12 до минор ',
'гиперборея': 'предтечи ',
'♫ Shaman King': 'Взгляни вокруг, оглянись назад, духи с тобою связаться '
'хотят. Мир не таков каким кажется он, чудесами каждый '
'окружен. Всё вокруг подвластно глазам, сделать свой выбор '
'должен ты сам, встреть свою судьбу - быть шаманом. Королём, '
'всех шаманов, королём если д '}

Comment: It works for me, thx so much! Could you explain to me why?